# Is there a way to get notified when my Shopify app is uninstalled?

Tags: shopify

I have a Shopify app, and am trying to understand the users' flow in my system.

Sometimes I see that API requests that I make fail, and when I check I get "Invalid API key or access token", when the same access token previously worked on this shop.

My only conclusion is that this user uninstalled my app at some point in time.

Is it possible to get some sort of notification when a user uninstalls my app? This can help me understand the user flow better and confirm the reason API requests fail. I could implement this by constantly polling every shop that installed my app, but that's rather clumsy - is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can register a webhook - an HTTP call that will call an endpoint of your choosing when a certain event happens. In this case the event you want to listed to is 'app/uninstalled'.

See http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html for more details.

Comment: This is a great answer. To supplement - Shopify has an page that shows all 'events' for your app, including app installs & uninstalls, the shop IDs that installed, etc. Great stuff.